# Why the program cann`t run properly through adb shell?

Tags: android, linux, shell, adb

1. adb shell
   #nohup /data/hello_test > /dev/null 2>&1 &
2. adb shell "nohup /data/hello_test > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

The first way is ok, the program can run at background.

While the second way is bad, the program is not running via 'ps -elf'.

Comment: Please **format** your question so that code parts are displayed properly (fixed font, each statement on its own line). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: What is the meaning of the sentencd _input the line at windows cmd_?

Comment: Whiy is this tagged _cmd_ and _linux_? Don't these tags contradict each other?

Comment: In the first command the local shell ignores everything after the `#`, so it's just `adb shell` and enters an interactive session